# Tabs in WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, webforms, tabs

I'm trying to create a set of tabs at runtime and they were, for a time, working correctly- however now they just seem to display the contents of all tabs underneath the previously rendered tab. As silly as it seems, as far as I can tell, in terms of code nothing has changed since the code was working so I am a little confused as to what is going on...

For the purpose of this example I will not use a loop, although this seems irrespective as the loop doesn't appear to be the problem.

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlTabs">
    <ul runat="server" id="ulSections" />
</asp:Panel>
```

I've come to the conclusion that my code must be at fault so here is the C#:

```
HtmlGenericControl liTab = new HtmlGenericControl("li");                        
HtmlGenericControl anTab = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
anTab.Attributes.Add("href", "#Tab1");
anTab.InnerText = Tab1;
liTab.Controls.Add(anTab);
ulSections.Controls.Add(liTab);

var pnl = new Panel();
pnl.ID = Tab1;
pnlTabs.Controls.Add(pnl);
```

I place my controls and what not on the "pnl". Can anyone please tell me what my mistake is?

Comment: This is most likely a css issue - has that changed?

Comment: I have checked the source code and as far as I can tell CSS has not changed. It seems logical that it would be the CSS as the code above was working and now isn't but I cannot tell what could have changed and if so how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered what the problem was, it was basically that the InnerText of "anTab" cannot be the same as the href attribute of "anTab" as this causes confusion and results in the content from all tabs to appear only in the first (selected) tab, while the remaining tabs don't function.

For example, the following code works correctly as the InnerText of "anTab" is "Tab 1" and the href is looking for a control with the ID "Tab1", which is the ID of the panel.

```
HtmlGenericControl liTab = new HtmlGenericControl("li");                        
HtmlGenericControl anTab = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
anTab.Attributes.Add("href", "#Tab1");
anTab.InnerText = "Tab 1";
liTab.Controls.Add(anTab);
ulSections.Controls.Add(liTab);

var pnl = new Panel();
pnl.ID = "Tab1";
pnlTabs.Controls.Add(pnl);
```

Below we can see that the InnerText of "anTab" is the same as the href and the ID of the panel we wish to use as the tab, this causes the confusion as the href now assumes you want the "tab click" to point to itself instead of the actual panel.

```
HtmlGenericControl liTab = new HtmlGenericControl("li");                        
HtmlGenericControl anTab = new HtmlGenericControl("a");
anTab.Attributes.Add("href", "#Tab1");
anTab.InnerText = "Tab1";
liTab.Controls.Add(anTab);
ulSections.Controls.Add(liTab);

var pnl = new Panel();
pnl.ID = "Tab1";
pnlTabs.Controls.Add(pnl);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//THIS ADDS THE <A> to the <LI>
liTab.Controls.Add(anTab);

//THIS ADDS THE <LI> to the <UL>
ulSections.Controls.Add(liTab);

//THIS CODE Appear to have nothing to do with anything.
var pnl = new Panel();
pnl.ID = Tab1;
pnlTabs.Controls.Add(pnl);
```

Can you confirm if the HTML is even being rendered in the html when you View Source.

Where in your code behind is this code... in a button click, on Page Load, On Init ?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes of course, the HTML is being rendered (and looks correct as far as I can see) and the code behind is in the Page_Load. The "pnl" is where I have placed the content of the tab, i.e. textboxes and such.

Comment: I've also noticed that "#<Name Of Tab>" has started appearing in the URL when I click on an unselected tab, this wasn't happening before either.